# How to make core plot auto change orientation when device is rotated?

Tags: core-plot

I'm trying to have core plot to automatically redraw a bar chart when orientation is changed just like in the provided example (CPTTest-iphone). I made some search on google but no luck. I do have the the CPTGraphHostingView property autoresizingMask set to true and in the nib file its view mode is set to "Scale to Fill". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or other configuration i am missing? Thank you.

Comment: BTW I have the graph view in a tab.

Comment: Is it just not redrawing, or is it not resizing at all?

Comment: Well there is no behaviour when the phone change orientation. The bar chart stays the same.

Comment: Core-Plot doesn't have any support for auto rotation. You're going to have to detect the change and do it yourself.

Comment: But how does it do it in the core plot bar chart example provided in the source code? There is no code handling rotation and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you detect an orientation change, you need to change the dimensions of your `CPTGraphHostingView`, then call `reloadData` on all the plots in your graph.  Something like this:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    self.hostingView.frame = CGRectMake( /* new dimensions for your hosting view */ );
    for (CPTPlot *p in self.graph.allPlots)
    {
        [p reloadData];
    }
}
```

You might also need to fix up the labels and tick marks on your axes, and the padding on the plotAreaFrame to accommodate the new size of the hosting view.

Comment: I just realized this question was asked 3 years ago... OP probably doesn't care anymore, but I hope this answer might help someone else.